# Intuition underlying a linear algebra result

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**RESULT**

For any $m\times n$ matrix $\textbf{A}$ and $m\times p$ matrix $\textbf{B}$, $\mathcal{C}(B)\subset\mathcal{C}(A)$ if and only if there exists an $n\times p$ matrix $\textbf{F}$ such that $\textbf{B} = \textbf{A}\textbf{F}$, where $\mathcal{C}(X)$ represents the column space of $\textbf{X}$.

**MY QUESTION**

I would like to know if someone could provide me an intuition underlying this matrix analysis result. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition ${\cal C}(B)\subset {\cal B}(A)$ means that every column of $B$ is a linear combination of columns of $A$. How many scalars do you need for each column of $B$? Well, as many as $A$'s column. More succinctly, 
$B=AF$
for some $n\times p$ matrix $F$. Why $p$ columns? That's because $B$ has $p$ columns.